# How can I report all subdomains pageviews in a GA4 Property?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a website with language based subdomains, there are 65 languages. Subdomains are like en.domain.com, fr.domain.com, de.domain.com... etc.

I want to view the report with subdomains in GA4. But I can't find any solution.

I can do that with view filter in old GA universal analytics, but GA4 does not have this option.

I'dont want to add all subdomains as new websites. How can I report pageviews with subdomains in one GA4 property.

Comment: Consider asking your question in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/